# show the output original DataFrame and edited

Tags: pandas, dataframe

its newbie here again.
i want to ask you again, how to show the original output then show the modify or edited output again.
this is my code

```
import pandas as pd

source = r'C:\Users\pulun\hbrag08\Durga Software\Complete Python Package\Python for Data Science\04. Pandas\DataFrame\employee_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(source,
                   usecols=['eno','ename','esal','city','country'],
                   index_col='eno',
                   sep=';')

df.rename(columns={'country': 'country name'},inplace=True)

print(df.sort_values(['esal']).loc[df['country name'].isin(
    ['Indonesia', 'USSR'])].head(n=6))


df.loc[(df['esal'] <= 1300000) & (df['country name'].isin(
    ['Indonesia', 'USSR']))] = df.loc[(df['esal'] <= 1300000) & (df['country name'].isin(
        ['Indonesia', 'USSR']))].apply(lambda x: x*2)

print('your solution here')
```

the original output is this

```
                 ename        esal                    city country name
eno
2840       Duffy Stood  1039768.45    9488 Milwaukee Plaza         USSR
5590     Sawyere Clogg  1096587.82  3409 Rockefeller Alley         USSR
730       Garret Attew  1104028.84          7 Walton Point         USSR
9040    Marve Coalburn  1207724.68          97 Susan Point         USSR
1620   Chrotoem Cleeve  1280881.36                     NaN         USSR
9500  Eleanore Cabrera  1294722.19          2401 Hovde Way    Indonesia
```

what i want is similar with output above, but with esal are doubled.

the after output must be look like these below:

```
                 ename        esal                    city country name
eno
2840       Duffy Stood  2079536.90   9488 Milwaukee Plaza         USSR
5590     Sawyere Clogg  2193175.64  3409 Rockefeller Alley         USSR
730       Garret Attew  2208057.68          7 Walton Point         USSR
9040    Marve Coalburn  1207724.68          97 Susan Point         USSR
1620   Chrotoem Cleeve  2415449.36                     NaN         USSR
9500  Eleanore Cabrera  2589444.38          2401 Hovde Way    Indonesia
```

For your help, i say many thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'doubled'? pls explain

Comment: i mean double their salary who come from Indonesia and USSR which their salary is less than 1400000.
i express 'doubled' by this code -> apply(lambda x: x*2)

Comment: All you need is: df['esal'] = df['esal']*2

Comment: i state this print statement s
print('your solution here')

, please fill the blank. What i need is get same ename before i double it with several requirement as i say before.

for example i need to get ename Duffy Stood after i double their salary

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import pandas as pd

source = r'C:\Users\pulun\hbrag08\Durga Software\Complete Python Package\Python for Data Science\04. Pandas\DataFrame\employee_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(source,
                   usecols=['eno','ename','esal','city','country'],
                   index_col='eno',
                   sep=';')

df.rename(columns={'country': 'country name'},inplace=True)

print(df.sort_values(['esal']).loc[df['country name'].isin(
    ['Indonesia', 'USSR'])].head(n=6))


df = df[(df['esal'] <= 1300000) & (df['country name'].isin(
        ['Indonesia', 'USSR']))]
df['esal'] = df['esal']*2

print(df)
```

Comment: i am happy with my current code sir, i just want to get the same ename result as i write above to check whether is my code work or not (do they get double salary increasement or not)

so that i give print statement
print('your solution here')

please give me the solution to fill the print statement

sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
df.loc[(df['esal'] <= 1300000) & (df['country name'].isin(
    ['Indonesia', 'USSR']))] = df.loc[(df['esal'] <= 1300000) & (df['country name'].isin(
        ['Indonesia', 'USSR']))].apply(lambda x: x*2)
```

with these lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
df['esal'] = np.where((df['esal'] <= 1300000) & (df['country name'].isin(['Indonesia', 'USSR'])), df['esal']*2, df['esal'])
```

Comment: i don't want replacing sir, what i want is just before and after output must have same name. for ex: a:1, b:2, c:3 then i double who salary is less than 3. before output i will get a and b, then i need to find a and b again to check their salary.

sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new column called `esal_orig` and you can compare before and after.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['esal_orig'] = df['esal']

mask = ( (df['esal'] <= 1300000) &
         (df['country name'].isin(['Indonesia', 'USSR']))
       )

df['esal'] = np.where(mask, df['esal']*2, df['esal'])

print(df[['esal_orig', 'esal']])
```

```
   esal_orig    esal
0    1039768 2079537
1    1096588 2193176
2    1104029 2208058
3    1207725 2415449
4    1280881 2561763
5    1294722 2589444
```

Comment: can't we do with another way? Sorry i just want to learn something

Because if i apply your solution, i have to count/process all rows is it need to be doubled or not.

in this case i just get 6 entries to double. i just want to find them only.

Comment: and will i get same ename which same before and after i double it?

Comment: When you modify the original dataframe and column, how else are you going to compare it? If you do that, the only way is to create a temporary column and print the two. Otherwise, you'll have to do them on-the-fly. `print(pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask, df['esal']*2, df['esal'])))`  `print(df['esal'])`

Comment: You can can create a separate data frame that includes only those rows and double the values. There are lots of ways to do it, but ultimately it boils down to the fact that if you want to compare one value with another by looking at it, you're going to have to keep the original and create a new column and double it.